# Why does GoogleMapsOptions not able to style?

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 4 and I have implemented the Google Maps API. The map works fine, however when i go to style it, some of the updates do not change. In my example if I change some of the camera options, those do change perfectly fine. However, when I want to add styles or gestures, those changes are not reflected.

```
let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
  camera: {
    target: {
      lat: 43.0741904,
      lng: -89.3809802
    },
    zoom: 15,
    tilt: 30
  },
  styles: [
    {
      "featureType":"poi",
      "stylers":[
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  gestures:{
    rotate:true
  }
};

this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be run on an actual device. I think that the browser does not support styled maps or something.